# Getting Wordpress Post Permalink without post-name

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

My defalut wordpress permalink structure is set to `http://example.com/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%`. I need to generate the post permalink without the `%postname%` part, without changing the default permalink structure.

I need this to set Disqus Comment URL. So when Disqus Comment loads on a post with `http://example.com/tech/123/example-tech-post` permalink, the Disqus Thread URL is set to `http://example.com/tech/123` only.

Is there a way to generate post permalink that way?

I tried `<?php echo get_permalink('', 1); ?>`. But that returns this `http://example.com/tech/123/%postname%`, that removes `example-tech-post` from the URL, but instead adds `%postname%`.

I'm trying to get just `http://example.com/tech/123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_post_ancestors($post->ID)`, or `dirname(get_permalink( $post->ID ))`